# Any way to dial international calling codes automatically based on my location?

Tags: phone-app, roaming, international-prefix

I do a fair amount of international traveling (currently mostly between the U.S. and Mexico, but will be visiting Europe, Africa, and South America soon, too), and am looking for a dialing app that lets me set international dialing rules, so to speak, for each of my contacts.

[This post](http://androidforums.com/android-applications/413525-international-dialing-codes-app.html) describes pretty well what I'm looking for, and an app for PalmOS that apparently did it pretty well.

In short, I should be able to:

- Specify a country for each contact phone number
- Specify the country where I am located (either automatically by GPS location, or I can select my location, or a dialing profile, or whatever)
- Then when I dial, it will automatically dial the appropriate country code before the number.

Example scenario:

> - I have a contact entry for Bob, who's phone number is 123-555-1234, and he is in the U.S.
> - When I am in the U.S., Bob is automatically dialed as `123-555-1234`
> - When I am in Mexico, Bob is automatically dialed as `00-1-123-555-1234`

*or*

> - I have a contact entry for Alice, who's phone number is 33-33-12-34-56, and she is in Mexico.
> - When I am in the U.S., Alice is automatically dialed as `011-52-33-33-12-34-56`
> - When I am in Mexico, Alice is automatically dialed as `33-33-12-34-56`

Please note this question is *not* about how to select the cheapest calling plan for each number, or making international calls with Skype or another VoIP service.  It's simply about dialing the proper international exit codes when doing standard "direct-dial" with whichever mobile provider I'm using.

Comment: Generally speaking, we do "How can I do X?" but not "Is there an app that does X?" questions.  In this case I think it's pretty much one and the same (I don't see any non-app way to solve this problem).  That said, if you phrased it the former way it would be helpful in discouraging the bad "shopping" style app-rec questions and might get you a better response :)

Comment: @MatthewRead: Thanks for the suggestions.  I've updated the question to hopefully be more inline with your suggestions.  I've also added some examples, and removed a reference to VoIP to hopefully make it more clear what specific functionality I'm looking for.

Comment: Can't you just save the numbers in international form? For example, Bob's would be `+1-123-555-1234` and Alice's `+52-33-33-12-34-56`.

Comment: @onik: I may be showing my ignorance here, but I don't think `+52-33-33-12-34-56` will work when I'm dialing from within Mexico... but maybe I'm wrong about that? It's certainly worth a try next time I'm in Mexico (next week)

Comment: @Flimzy Not sure about Mexico, but it works in all the countries I've been to in Europe.

Comment: @onik: I will definitely try it then, next week.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just save the numbers in international form. For example, Bob's would be `+1-123-555-1234` and Alice's `+52-33-33-12-34-56`.

Comment: Thanks! This is working quite well for me, except when receiving texts... So I have asked a [followup question](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/22041/13613).